# Sliding up and side to side using CSS animations

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I'm trying to slide some small music note icons up and out of the viewport, and I want them to move from side to side as they are sliding up and out of the page, almost as if they are swaying whilst sliding up.

I've managed to get them to slide from side to side, and up, but i'm having trouble getting them to do it at the same time.

If possible I'd like them to fade out as they reach the top of the page too, but I realise that might be quite tricky.

Here's how far I've got up to now - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpEWqr

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-music one"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music two"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music three"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music four"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music five"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music six"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music seven"></i>
```

And here's the CSS (icons from font-awesome)

```
  .fa-music {
  color: red; 
  font-size: 35px;
}

.one, .four, .six {
 margin-top: 200px; 
 margin-left: 200px;
 position: absolute; 
 animation: sideslidetwo 2s 5, slideup 2s; 
}

.two, .five, .seven {
  margin-top: 150px; 
  margin-left: 250px; 
  animation: sideslide 2s 5, slideup 2s; 
}

.three, .eight {
  margin-left: 100px; 
  animation: sideslidetwo 2s 5, slideup 2s; 
}

@keyframes sideslide {
    0% {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
      transform:translate3d(30px, 00px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform:translate3d(-50px, 00px, 0px);
    }
  }

@keyframes sideslidetwo {
    0% {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
      transform:translate3d(-30px, 00px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform:translate3d(50px, 00px, 0px);
    }
  }

@keyframes slideup {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -500px, 0px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the general concept. Just use `translate()` to animate the x and y axis, and `opacity` to fade them out

```css
.fa-music {
  color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
  animation: shimmy 1s forwards;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50vh;
}

@keyframes shimmy {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10vh,-10vh);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(10vh,-20vh);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-10vh,-30vh);
    opacity: .4;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(10vh,-40vh);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-10vh,-50vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-music one"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music two"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music three"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music four"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music five"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music six"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music seven"></i>
</div>
```